# Short experience period on resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, new-job, job-change

I've 1.8 years of experience with my 1st employer and 2 Months with 2nd employer and I'm looking for a job change because I'm not able to work with my 2nd employer because of kind of work and technologies are used in the project.

should I mention 2 Months experience on my resume?

Comment: If you 'can't work with second employer due to issues...' it would be best to leave it off.  In short, you're not gaining meaningful experience.

Comment: @MeredithPoor Actually I've given notice of 2 months on 25th nov within 2 months I need to find a new job.

Comment: Hey VI, and welcome to [workplace.se]! The question that Jim linked above will probably give you a good starting place. If you think your question is different and the answers there don't help you, please [edit] your question to help clarify what the differences are so we can help you out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My opinion is, mention that short experience period on your resume.

Yes, it could hurt. People would wonder why you have such a short period experience.

But, they'll understand you are looking for a new job possibly because of that short period. If the job they are offering is similar to your current job, they won't call you. And you don't want to do that kind of job again, do you? In this way, you'll save everybody's time.

Another reason, you don't want to leave a gap in the resume. People would wonder you were unemployed during that period if you don't mention it. They would think you lie on your resume if they find out you were actually with some company during that period. You would be hurt even worse in this case.

Answer (score 4):

With such a short career I think it's worth while as long as you can get a positive reference of some sort from your current employer. In this case I'd almost settle for an HR "yes, V...I... worked for us for two months", but ideally it would be someone you work with who's willing to say "keen, but not a good fit" or something.

If you do it right you'll convey that you're someone who is willing to admit your mistakes, learn from them, and move on. Having someone you work with willing to give you a reference also says you haven't made your current employer too grumpy even though it's not working out for you.

I think your goal should be to be able to portray it as a learning experience. "I expected ..." but either "I was wrong and in retrospect when they said ... I should have realised" or "it turns out I don't want to do {what they do} and since I've done {what you do} before I'd rather continue down that path". Try very hard to avoid giving the impression that you're just surfing round trying things in the hope that one will catch your interest.

You can usually get away with this as long as you can show that you have actually learned from it and it doesn't happen often. I've done it with 20 years experience, by saying that as predicted by one of my referees I really did not enjoy working in a particular industry and I want out, despite the generous pay and other attractions. It's important that you have a good explanation that does not apply to the potential new employer.